# cannot install tensorflow on raspberrypi 4

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, node-red, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to install tensorflow for the purpose of installing node-red-contrib-tf-model in node red on a raspberry pi 4. I followed these instructions on https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-tf-model

[image: image of instructions]

However, when I run npm install, I am met with errors.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd ~/.node-red/
pi@raspberrypi:~/.node-red $ npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.7.3
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.14.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! CPU-linux-1.7.3.tar.gz
npm ERR! * Downloading libtensorflow
npm ERR! /home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/scripts/install.js:95
npm ERR!     throw new Error(`Unsupported system: ${libType}-${platform}-${os.arch()}`);
npm ERR!           ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Unsupported system: cpu-linux-arm64
npm ERR!     at getPlatformLibtensorflowUri (/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/scripts/install.js:95:11)
npm ERR!     at downloadLibtensorflow (/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/scripts/install.js:129:7)
npm ERR!     at async run (/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/scripts/install.js:190:5)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2023-06-24T07_22_10_202Z-debug-0.log

pi@raspberrypi:~/.node-red $ cd node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node
bash: cd: node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node: No such file or directory
```

So there is no file or directory for @tensorflow...

Comment: The version must to be equal or greater then 1.5.1 (up to 1.7.3) , You are trying to install 1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your system hasn't have installed Tensorflow for C. Try the solution from this [link](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-get-a-tensorflow-c-binding-for-raspberry-pi/) to install it:

1. Check if tensorflow itself installed
2. Then install bindings:

```bash
sudo apt install -y autoconf automake libtool curl make g++ unzip
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
./configure
bazel build --config opt //tensorflow/tools/lib_package:libtensorflow
tar -C /usr/local -xzf bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/lib_package/libtensorflow.tar.gz
sudo ldconfig
```

Then try to install tensoflow again

Comment: I have tried installing tensorflow:
pi@raspberrypi:~/.node-red $ pip freeze | grep tensorflow
tensorflow==2.12.0
tensorflow-cpu-aws==2.12.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.12.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.32.0
.

No problem installing tensorflow, but the file directory just doesn't appear in node-red